# Ajax unable to call function, ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have this code in my view

```
                       $("#testCheck").on('click', function () { $.ajax({
                             type: "GET",
                             url: '@Url.Action("HandleDriverOptions", "Test")',
                             success: function (result) {
                                     $(".testMessage").html(result)
                             }
                        })});                                            
                       <div id=".testMessage"></div>
```

Followed by the following code in the controller

```
     public ActionResult Test(String test) {return Content("Test Success", "text/plain");}
```

However in the div its not printing the Test Success please advise

Comment: your selector is wrong, also add `debugger` word `inside` click and success `callbacks` and investigate more.

Comment: @vera Check my updated answer and let me know if it don't work.

Comment: @Chirag Hi thanks for the help! yeap it does, even with the quotes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misplaced Controller name and method name in URL. Try following code.

```
$("#testCheck").on('click', function () { $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '@Url.Action("Test", "HandleDriverOptions")',
       success: function (result) {
       $("#testMessage").html(result)
       }
 })});                                            
 <div id="testMessage"></div>
```

> Another thing to notice here is, You'll have to put this whole code inside script tag of your view so that `url: '@Url.Action("Test", "HandleDriverOptions")'` **could be parsed by razor**.

And When you put same inside view you'll have to remove `quotes` from actual URL. So your final code would be look like..`url: @Url.Action("Test", "HandleDriverOptions")`

Hope it helps.